# Why is $ undefined in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have the following code in Meteor:

```
if Meteor.isClient
    Meteor.startup ->
        $('#main').html("Hi Meteor")
```

I get an error telling me "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  However, in the console if I reference jQuery's $ it works fine.

I also added the jquery package, but I don't think it was really needed since the core of Meteor uses jQuery.  However, the error is the same.

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Are you trying to access to ´$('#main')´ element on ready? Maybe you are trying to access it before DOM is loaded

Comment: Try `jQuery('#main').html("Hi Meteor")`

Comment: @kmsdev: That wouldn't give a reference error. A selector that doesn't find anything isn't an error in jQuery.

Comment: @Guffa Yes, you are right, my bad. If jQuery is already loaded it shouldn't give an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the jQuery object when the DOM is ready. 
The best place is in the `onRendered` callback of a template. You can do this in any template including the body:

```
Template.body.onRendered(function() {
  $('#main').html("Hi Meteor");
});
```

OR

```
Template.yourTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $('#main').html("Hi Meteor");
});
```